# Should there be an article before “cell phone”?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, countable-nouns

From [an online article](http://www.toledoblade.com/Editorials/2005/07/14/Talking-heads.html):

> Many drivers tool around town or take long drives **with cell phone in hand**, one eye on the road but their mind clearly someplace else.

Since "cell phone" is of course countable, shouldn't the sentence be:

> Many drivers tool around town or take long drives *with **a**  cell phone in hand*, one eye on the road but their mind clearly someplace else.

Is it a grammatical error or a special usage in the original text?

I am interested in knowing if the "with something in hand" construction warrants an exception or if it is common practice to omit the article in similar constructions.

Comment: I think it is an acceptable exception, but by no means a rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although "cell phone" is countable, the sentence sounds fine. In the expression "[with] x in hand", the article can be omitted. I think it sometimes sounds a little poetic, but there's nothing wrong with it.

Here are some examples of it in use:

> ‘Your regards, Edith, my dear?’ said Mrs. Skewton, pausing, pen in hand, at the postscript.
>   <sub>[Dombey & Son](https://books.google.com/books?id=oOpLAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq="%E2%80%98Your+regards,+Edith,+my+dear?%E2%80%99) by Charles Dickens, 1847</sub>

> With bag in hand, Tara slipped out of the room, running up the stairs toward her bedroom.
>   <sub>[In Her Presence: A Husband's Dirty Secret](https://books.google.com/books?id=EJMLSEOw4TMC&pg=PA282&lpg=PA282&dq="with+bag+in+hand".) by Nancy Weaver, 2004</sub>

> Or, what if someone just yells — with gun in hand — he’s a good guy?
>   <sub>[Questions for the Good Guy with a Gun](https://midcenturymodernmag.com/questions-for-the-good-guy-with-a-gun-23274cab39d5) by Hersch Wilson, 2018</sub>

Comment: +1 Though omitting the article is wider than just "[with] x in hand". For example: "There she goes again, with fishnets on, and dreadlocks in her hair". I have no idea what rule governs it though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is **a grammatical mistake** in the original test.

According to the dictionaries*, the plural form of "**cell phone**" (or cellphone) is **cell phones** (or cellphones). When it's mentioned in its singular form it's necessary to put an article before (definite or indefinite). Therefore, the original text has a grammatical mistake.

Now, when talking about "**with cell phone in hand**" is not different from other sentences. It is not an exception for the singular-plural system. Google shows [39.5K](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22with%20cell%20phone%20in%20hand%22&oq=%22with%20cell%20phone%20in%20hand%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4471j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) results for "with cell phone in hand" and [121K](https://www.google.com.ua/search?ei=fF3qWt7UJ4_QkwWXrq-YAw&q=%22with%20a%20cell%20phone%20in%20hand%22&oq=%22with%20a%20cell%20phone%20in%20hand%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1.150408.150513.0.150795.2.2.0.0.0.0.99.99.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.98....0.4oZhWRS1Ms8) for "with **a** cell phone in hand" 3 times more approximately for the correct one. In addition, a lot of results of these 39.5K results are in titles in which there is a reduction of using indefinite articles.

*References:

- [Word-Web online](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=cell%20phone).
- [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cell-phone?q=CELL%20PHONE).
- [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/CELL%20PHONE).

[See here also - on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/theyre-using-a-cell-phone-vs-theyre-using-cell-phones).

Comment: Well, "cell phone" being a count noun is actually part of the premise of my question and has been stated in the question. I am interested in knowing if the "with something in hand" construction warrants an exception or if it is common practice to omit the article in similar constructions.

Comment: So you have to edit your question, because your things are not there. You asked simply "Should there be an article before “cell phone”?" and you gave an example for a text that states cell phone without an article. Anyway I added the relevant information to answer your question in the comment as well. But Kindly edit your question in order to be clearer for others too.

Comment: Google's estimated # of hits is wrong though. It's actually [88 for no article](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22with+cell+phone+in+hand%22&ei=IKzqWoSjIqy3ggelkr3wDA&start=80&sa=N&biw=1440&bih=733) & [47 for with indefinite article](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22with+a+cell+phone+in+hand%22&ei=jKzqWqX0D5C1ggeUvLXQAQ&start=40&sa=N&biw=1440&bih=733). It's usually [pretty far off like this](https://searchengineland.com/why-google-cant-count-results-properly-53559), so you can't use it for much.